# how to download charts as a pdf file?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, chart.js

Below code is used to plot the chart using chartjs library and now iam looking to download that chart as a pdf when btnExport is clicked the PDF should automatically downloaded Using itextsharp or any other method

Any small suggestions is helpful

```
<body>
        <form runat="server">
  <div class="container">
    <canvas id="myChart" runat="server"></canvas>
      <asp:Button ID="btnExport" OnClick="btnExport_Click" runat="server" Text="Button" />
  </div>

  <script>
    let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

    let massPopChart = new Chart(myChart, {
      type:'bar', // bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
      data:{
        labels:['Boston', 'Worcester', 'Springfield', 'Lowell', 'Cambridge', 'New Bedford'],
        datasets:[{
          label:'Population',
          data:[
            617594,
            181045,
            153060,
            106519,
            105162,
            95072
          ],
          //backgroundColor:'green',
          backgroundColor:[
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.6)',
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)'
          ],
          borderWidth:1,
          borderColor:'#777',
          hoverBorderWidth:3,
          hoverBorderColor:'#000'
        }]
      },
      options:{
        title:{
          display:true,
          text:'Largest Cities In Massachusetts',
          fontSize:25
        },
        legend:{
          display:true,
          position:'right',
          labels:{
            fontColor:'#000'
          }
        },
        layout:{
          padding:{
            left:50,
            right:0,
            bottom:0,
            top:0
          }
        },
        tooltips:{
          enabled:true
        }
      }
    });
  </script>

            </form>
</body>
```

Please help me to converting that chart into pdf

Comment: There's already an answer to this question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46264476/2358409

Comment: Thanks,It is working. Above code is rendering only one page pdf. can you please help me for multiple pages too