# Merge 2 charts into 1 chart using update button (chart.js)

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I just want to know how do you combine 2 charts into 1 chart using chart.js

I want to merge the displayed charts (USING BUTTON -onclick function-)into 1 mixed chart so i can see the comparison of data

I've seen alot of mixed charts on chart.js but want to have 2 sets of charts first then turn into 1 set of chart

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/barrogocarlo/nudwgj3b/)

```
Here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chart.js docs:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

On button click you would incorporate this code

```
chart.data.labels.push(label);
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push(data);
    });
    chart.update();
```

Then to remove your other chart you would use chart.destroy().

Alternatively, you could load the data of the chart initially and change the visibility of the data series you want to show when clicked to none and set the old chart visibility to none. This would be lighter on clients if you are using large amounts of data sets and is easier to control when using jQuery's .toggle() function.

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.0.0-alpha/developers/api.html

Comment: could you incorporate it with with the existing jsfiddle that i made? so i can understand it clearly

Comment: Define each dataset as an object with properties instead, then populate the dataset array with your dataset objects.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can i ask if there's a way to export this chart/s into pdf?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46264021/export-html-content-with-chart-jscanvases-to-pdf