# How to create a chart in pdf using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have added the structure of my code using Nodejs. Using Nodejs I have added the data to create a pdf report. Using the same data values I need to create a chart in pdf

```
    const generatePdf = async (data, templateType) => {
    await page.setContent(html);
    const pdf = await page.pdf({
    margin: {
    top: 80,
    bottom: 80,
    left: 30,
    right: 30,
    top: 80
    }
    });
    await browser.close();
    return pdf;
    };
```

The above code is the current structure of my code and I need to create a chart in pdf. I have created a POC for creating chart in pdf like below code. Please help me to integrate the below code with my current structure using nodejs library -- jspdf with dynamic input in the above code.

```
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Line Chart</title>
        <!-- Include Chart.js library -->
    
        <canvas id="canvas" style="width:90vw">
        </canvas>
        <button id="saveExcel">Save xlsx</button> <button id="savePdf">Save pdf</button>
    
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.1/chart.umd.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/exceljs/4.4.0/exceljs.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.5/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <script>
            let chart = null,
                originalWidth, originalHeight;
            function TyLyReport() {
                const lineChartData = {
                    labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"],
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: 'Dataset 1',
                            borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                            data: [1000, 2000, 2500],
                            fill: false
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Dataset 2',
                            borderColor: '#FF4848',
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 72, 72, 0.2)',
                            data: [1016, 1800, 2900],
                            fill: false
                        }
                    ]
                };
    
               chart = new Chart("canvas", {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: lineChartData,
                    options: {
                        responsive: false,
                        animation: false,
                        maintainAspectRatio: false,
                        devicePixelRatio: 1,
                        scales: {
                            y: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    plugins: [
                        {
                            beforeDraw(chart) { // White background in the exported image
                                const { ctx, canvas } = chart;
                                ctx.save();
                                ctx.fillStyle = '#FFF';
                                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.offsetWidth, canvas.offsetHeight);
                                ctx.restore();
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });
    
                originalWidth = canvas.offsetWidth;
                originalHeight = canvas.offsetHeight;
            }
    
            function getChartImageForWidth(widthPx) {
                chart.resize(widthPx, widthPx * originalHeight / originalWidth);
                const returnData = {
                    image: chart.canvas.toDataURL("image/png").split(';base64,')[1],
                    width: chart.canvas.offsetWidth,
                    height: chart.canvas.offsetHeight
                };
                chart.resize(originalWidth, originalHeight);
                return returnData;
            }
    
    
    
            function exportToPdf(marginPx) {  // the top, left and right margins of the image wrt the pdf page
                const doc = new jspdf.jsPDF({ unit: "px", hotfixes: ["px_scaling"] });
                const pdfWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth(); // to fit width
                const { image } = getChartImageForWidth(pdfWidth - 2 * marginPx);
                doc.addImage(image, marginPx, marginPx);
                doc.save('chart_image.pdf');
            }
    
            TyLyReport();
            document.querySelector('#savePdf').addEventListener('click', () => exportToPdf(40));
        </script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

This html Script is POC for which I have created an chart in pdf and I need to integrate the same code with inputs from my code. can you please help to integrate a above code with my node js code. Using the html code I can able to create a chart in pdf but need to integrate in node js code. I have added the picture below for thc chart need to be added in the pdf.I have added the table which is already created inside the pdf based on that chart should be drawn in pdf

Comment: The code you posted is not debuggable as it makes reference to several missing pieces (template, data) and is presented as a library, not a runnable program.

Comment: I'll try to make a simple pupeteer example based on some fragments in your code

Comment: Here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/jyac6uf9/) where the downloaded pdf is generated by the page code, using the existing `jsPDF` code. And [this](https://jsfiddle.net/20y31wak/) is an example where the pdf is created by puppeteer, using `page.pdf()` which you already used. Obviously, the two fiddles don't run, the code is intended for `node`, I used the fiddles just to transmit the js code. Maybe you can update the details of the question based on those pieces of code, or something similar that can be easily executed by anybody.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Node canvas and Chart js, it will be similar to the code that you have provided except for the HTML part.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).